# Cauchy Problem depending on a parameter $a$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working with this Cauchy problem:

$$\begin{cases}
y'(x)=(y-2)^{2}\sin x \\ 
y(0)=a\\
\end{cases}$$
With $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have to find all the solutions as functions of $a$ and verify for which values of $a$ the solution has the domain the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

I started with separation of variables

$$\int_{y}^{a}\frac{1}{(t-2)^{2}}dt=\int_0^{x}\sin v dv$$ 
Obtaining:
$$\frac{1}{2-a}-\frac{1}{2-y}=-\cos x+1$$
Changing the sign of both terms:
$$\frac{1}{y-2}-\frac{1}{a-2}=\cos x-1$$

Ok, this should be the solution (maybe after some algebra it would be looks better).

For check the domain as funcion of $a$ I decided to rewrite the solution in this way:
$$(y-2)^{-1}-(a-2)^{-1}=\cos x-1$$
And
$$(y-2)^{-1}=(a-2)^{-1}+\cos x-1$$

Now, assuming I have done all right, how should I have to choose the range of values for $a$? 
Thank you very much :).

Comment: $(a-2)^{-1} + \cos x - 1 \ne 0, (a-2)^{-1} >2$ or $(a-1)^{-1} < 0$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What have you done? Have you elevated both terms to $+1$ power? Thank you :).

Comment: The RHS cannot equal 0, if you are going raise it $^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $a=2$, the solution is a constant $y(x) = 2$. This has domain $\Bbb R$
- If $a\ne 2$, the equation separates to

$$ \frac{dy}{(y-2)^2} = \sin x\ dx  $$
$$ \frac{1}{y-2} = \cos x + C $$

where $C = \frac{1}{a-2}-1$. The general solution is

$$ y(x) = 2 + \frac{1}{\cos x - 1 + \frac{1}{a-2}} $$

In order to have a domain of $\Bbb R$, you want to exclude all possible singularities, therefore the denominator has to be strictly positive or strictly negative. You also have

$$ \frac{1}{a-2}-2 < \cos x - 1 + \frac{1}{a-2} < \frac{1}{a-2} $$

There are two cases

- Strictly negative: $\frac{1}{a-2} < 0 \implies a < 2$
- Strictly positive: $0< \frac{1}{a-2}-2 \implies a < 2.5$

All of the above combined gives a range of $a < 2.5$

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. The solution is coherent with the result, so, well done! I have just another question: how you have found $C=\frac{1}{a-2}-1$? I've tried but I'm doing something wrong for sure. Thank you. :).

Comment: Just plug in $x=0$, $y=a$ in the second line and solve for $C$